# Why is {" "} automatically inserted in my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application, and sometimes I see `{" "}` automatically being added in my source code.
Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?
It's not creating any error or bug in application, what's the reason behind it?

For example:

```
<div className="pr-form display-block">
  <input
    type="radio"
    name="same"
    onChange={handleChange("create")}
    defaultValue={values.create}
  />{" "}
  Create a new requirement
  <br />
  <input
    type="radio"
    name="same"
    onChange={handleChange("reuse")}
    defaultValue={values.reuse}
  />{" "}
  Reuse a draft
  <br />
  <input
    type="radio"
    name="same"
    onChange={handleChange("existing")}
    defaultValue={values.existing}
  />{" "}
  Using an existing requirement
</div>
```

Comment: This is space "mark", without that there would be no space between component and text

Comment: My guess is this is a feature in the editor you are using to automatically put spaces between elements. That code would not spontaneously appear in your source files otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have plugin [eslint-plugin-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react) installed so It automatically add curly braces to whitespace when file saved
Alternatively, we can use `&nbsp;`(non-breaking spaces), `<span> </span>` or `\u00A0`
You can read more about this rule here [rules/jsx-curly-brace-presence](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-curly-brace-presence.md)

Examples of correct **code** for this rule:

```js
<Color text={"\u00a0"} />
<App>{"Hello \u00b7 world"}</App>;
<style type="text/css">{'.main { margin-top: 0; }'}</style>;
/**
 * there's no way to inject a whitespace into jsx without a container so this
 * will always be allowed.
 */
<App>{' '}</App>
<App>{'     '}</App>
<App>{/* comment */ <Bpp />}</App> // the comment makes the container necessary
```